# How can my form detect KeyDown events when another control has the focus?

Tags: delphi, keydown, registerhotkey

```
procedure TMainForm.KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (GetKeyState(Ord('Q'))<0) and (GetKeyState(Ord('W'))<0) and (GetKeyState(Ord('E'))<0)
  then ShowMessage('You pressed it');
end;
```

the above event only work if the Focus set to the Main Form.
if i run the application and keep pressing Tab and changing the Focus to any control on the Form it will disable this event until we change the Focus again to the main form ?

the Question is
**how i can detect the three keys are pressed even if the Focus not in the main form ?**

also i thought if i use **RegisterHotKey** but is not good idea to Register **Q,W and E** while my application is running.

```
procedure TMainForm.WMHotKey(var Msg: TWMHotKey);
begin
  if ActiveCaption = 'my Form Caption' then
  Begin
    if Msg.HotKey = HotKey1 then
    begin
      //DoSomething;
    end
    else
    if Msg.HotKey = HotKey2 then
    begin
      //DoSomething;
    end;
  End
  else
   //DoSomething;
end;
```

Comment: In what scenario do you wish to handle this key press? If a hot key is too global, what would be right?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz i don't know about it until now Thanks i try it, its works perfect, thanks for saving my day.

Comment: @Abdulrahman - You're welcome. Made it an answer..

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks i just set the KeyPreview Propert to Ture and it works

Comment: What if you have multiple forms?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan then should i use `RegisterHotKey` API  for the multiple form ?

Comment: Depends on what you want to happen. You didn't answer my question earlier.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i want to display a form using `ShowModal`

Comment: Never mind. I don't think you understand my question, but you probably have your answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set [`KeyPreview`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.KeyPreview) of the form to true.

> If `KeyPreview` is true, keyboard events occur on the form before they
>   occur on the active control. (The active control is specified by the
>   ActiveControl property.)
>
> If `KeyPreview` is false, keyboard events occur only on the active
>   control.
>
> Navigation keys (Tab, BackTab, the arrow keys, and so on) are
>   unaffected by `KeyPreview` because they do not generate keyboard
>   events. Similarly, when a button has focus or when its Default
>   property is true, the Enter key is unaffected by `KeyPreview` because
>   it does not generate a keyboard events.
>
> `KeyPreview` is false by default.